# Sill Pan for Exterior Door - Importance VS. Requirement

Tags: doors, waterproofing, exterior, installation, door-frame

I am installing a new secondary entrance door and deciding whether to use a plastic sill pan from HD or Lowes. Neither store, nor any lumber yards around me, carry these in stock. That leads me to question whether these are required by code (or by the building inspection department, who sometimes have "favorite" items they look for, whether code requirement or not). Some places we called said that we should just use flashing tape, which we were gonna use anyway, even with the sill pan. The door will have minimal to no overhang for protection from the elements.

Any ideas?

[image: Here's where the common threshold sill pan fits in the door installation:]

Comment: Is your question simply whether code requires a hard pan? You might mention where you are if that's the case. Code isn't universal.

Comment: what kind of door is it and what is the location of the door?    There is no reason to have a pan if the door is under a covered porch.

Comment: We are in NYS (sorry, I thought I had stated that)... and no as I said, the door will have almost no overhang or protection above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code does not require a sill pan for doors or windows.

However, I live in a high wind area and wind will drive rain up hill between every crack and crevice in siding, thresholds, etc.  Here it would be silly not to use a sill pan, but we use a one piece stainless steel pan AND set it in roofing mastic. We even use it at deep overhang areas like porches, because the walls, windows, doors, etc. are washed from time to time.

Comment: Thanks I accepted your answer. Since this door will not have much of an overhang or awning, we drove the 40 minutes to the nearest HD that carried a Suresill stopped pan. We still added flashing underneath and all around.

Comment: No leaks...you won’t regret it.